# Using CSS variables in LESS

Tags: css, less

This might seem basic, but I can't figure out how to use CSS variables in LESS?

variables.css:

```
.root {
    --header-color: white;
    --content-color: yellow;
}
```

styles.less:

```
@import "../variables.css";
.header {
   color: @header-color;
}
```

I get error "@header-color is undefined".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LESS allows you to use normal CSS code, so use one option could be just use the variable as CSS:

```
@import "../variables.css";
.header {
   color: var(--header-color);
}
```

Also, you can save the css var to a LESS var:

```
@import "../variables.css";
@header-color: var(--header-color);

.header {
   color: @header-color;
}
```

Comment: When we use this, its returning  `fade`: a.toHSL is not a function for darken function in less

Comment: @Pradeepa I will add a detailed warning to my answer later, mainly to avoid confusions, but to give you a short answer: is not possible to use css variables as parameters of less functions like `color: darken(var(--header-color), 50%)`.